# How to call a Rest webservice from Domino 8.5.3?

Tags: rest, lotus-domino

Looks like there is not much documentation available regarding how to develop a Rest consumer from Domino(8.5.3 in our case). I would like to know various  options available to achieve this. I am a Java developer, and would also like to know if Domino lotusScript can somehow take advantage of Java agent to call the Rest api. I know Java agents can be called from Domino, but I am not sure of exact process/API to achieve this. Anyway please let me know some standard options available, for developing the Rest consumer from Domino 8.5.3 .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think most simple way would be to deal with agents (Java or LotusScript - does not matter, but I would go with Java).

To trigger agent - here is an URL example

```
http://Host/Database/AgentName?OpenAgent&param=1
```

Read more about [URL commands for opening agents, forms, and navigators](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/2dba8b8000a7aeb185256c54004b8e44?OpenDocument)

> Domino lotusScript can somehow take advantage of Java agent to call
>   the Rest api.

I do not think so.
I would recommend to use Java.

The only benefit you may get from using LotusScript - it may run faster little bit. Each time you run java agent - it extract all related libraries to memory/disk (not sure) and only than start to run.

Answer (score 0):

If your LotusScript will be running on a Windows machine, you can use WinHTTP to make the necessary URL connections to access a REST service. That won't give you any help parsing and formatting data, though.

A better alternative would probably be to write your code that interacts with the REST service as a Java class, and then use [LS2J](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_ABOUT_LS2J.html) to give your LotusScript code a way to work with the Java objects and methods.